# Can't get an access to a companion object's field

Tags: scala, companion-object

I'm wondering, why can't a class get an access to a companion object's field?

```
class MyClass {
  println(val1) // not found, why?
}

object MyClass {
  val val1 = "str"
}
```

It should, it should even have an access to the private fields of `object MyClass`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that by using `MyClass.val1` instead of just `val1`.
I guest that's done to denote that companion object members can be accessed from anywhere (with default modifiers).

Comment: it should not be so because it's a companion object.

Comment: @Alex: I guess  that's by design and was reasoned along the lines of this comment: "The thing is, it's a lot easier to import something into your namespace if you want it than it is to unimport if you don't. And personally I already have enough problems with shadowing" (from http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2411.html#comment-8493). If you think so because you are reading "Programming in Scala", you might just have misunderstood it (see comment http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2411.html#comment-8427).

Comment: hasn't that been differently recently? I think I have used it without importing previously.

Comment: @Alex: you could just import companion object's methods like this: `class MyClass { import MyClass._; println(val1) }`;

Comment: @senia, my last question is not about that. Of course, I can do that, but the object doesn't necessarily  have to be a companion object.

Comment: @senia, and since it's a companion object, it shouldn't require importing itself to "companion" class.

Comment: @Alex: why not? There could be methods with the same name in object and class. For instance: `List.apply(1).apply(0)`. Importing by default leads to name collisions.

Comment: @senia, has that always been so? If I recall correctly, previously there wasn't a need to import the fields of a companion object, they were accessible by default.

Comment: @Alex: the oldest scala version [available](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/all.html) on `scala-lang.org` is [`2.5.0.final`](http://scala-lang.org/download/2.5.0.final.html). And you have to import companion object methods manually in that version.

Comment: @Alex: you could see all changes about companion objects in [Changelog](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html). The only change about companion object was in `Version 2.1.8 (23-Aug-2006)` [Relaxation of Private Access](http://www.scala-lang.org/download/changelog.html#relaxation_of_private_access). Before that version you couldn't even call private methods of companion object in class.

Answer (score 6):

It's debatable that a class "should" have access to its companion object fields by default. Consider the not uncommon case where the companion object's `apply` method is used as a factory, and the object itself has an `apply` method to do something different. It would get confusing to read the code and know which method was meant! [Roland Ewald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109942/roland-ewald) made a comment to another answer quoting http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/2411.html#comment-8493 which sums it up nicely:

> "The thing is, it's a lot easier to import something into your namespace if you want it than it is to unimport if you don't. And personally I already have enough problems with shadowing."

And that gives the answer. Use `import` thus:

```
class MyClass {
  import MyClass._
  println(val1) // Should see it now!
}

object MyClass {
  val val1 = "str"
}
```